# how can i sort dd/mm/yy date format in datagrid using flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid

i used array collection sort method like below . but still sorting wrongly .  Any other solution for sort date  using flex3

```
public function SortingDate(ArrColl : ArrayCollection, field : String) : void{
            var sortA:Sort = new Sort();
            sortA.fields=[new SortField(field,false,true,null)];
            ArrColl.sort=sortA;
            ArrColl.refresh();
        }
```

it's sorting but day only sorting like

```
31/08/10
30/09/10
28/07/10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a sortCompareFunction on the DataGridColumn you are using for dates.

It looks like this:

```
dateColumnSortCompareFunc(obj1:Object, obj2:Object) : int {
  // here you translate your object into things that can be evaluated
  // and return 1 if obj1 > obj2, 0 if they are equal, and -1 if obj1 < obj2
  // for example
  var d1:Date = new Date(obj1);
  var d2:Date = new Date(obj2);
  return ( d1.valueOf() > d2.valueOf() ) ? 1 : ( d1.valueOf() < d2.valueOf() ) ? -1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: private function date_sortCompareFunc(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int {
                var dateA:Date = new Date(Date.parse(itemA.enddatetime));
                var dateB:Date = new Date(Date.parse(itemB.enddatetime));
                return ObjectUtil.dateCompare(dateA, dateB);
            }

Comment: In above enddatetime is datafield in datagrid  i used sortcompareFunction for compare (dd/mm/yy) format string  but not sorting.could u certificate me

Comment: I use Date.valueOf() because it's simpler. Why convert it to a String first just to use Date.parse()? Date.valueOf() gives you milliseconds.

Comment: i used Date.valueOf()also , but shows wrongly Mr.Robusto , Thank you for Response me

Comment: <mx:DataGridColumn   headerText="Due Date" dataField="enddatetime" sortCompareFunction="dateColumnSortCompareFunc"  />  i add ur function like this sortCompareFunction .  enddatetime format is dd/mm/yy . is it right ?

Comment: In this case you need to put the function name in curly braces like so: `sortCompareFunction="{dateColumnSortCompareFunc}"` That way it gets treated as the object that it is.